# Converting to varbinary adds spaces

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying in insert some data from Sql Server into MySQL using OPENQUERY

```
SELECT 1,1,'0123456789','Test Contact' INTO #tempcontacts
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY([PBXA_MYSQL],'SELECT relation_id,unit,name,number FROM asterisk.contacts')
SELECT id,unit_id,CONVERT(varbinary(100),name),CONVERT(varbinary(50),RIGHT(number,8)) FROM #tempcontacts
DROP TABLE #tempcontacts
```

The fields on MySQL are varbinary and i'm unable to change that. The data is inserted but every character has a space added. It looks like this:

```
name                   number
T e s t  C o n t a c t 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Is there a better way to convert to varbinary?

Thanks

Comment: What is column type of source table (from what you convert to varbinary)?

Comment: @B001 He inserts from SQL Server to MySQL

Comment: @sepupic my bad :)